# Dynamically reference bundles for integration test with Pax Exam

Tags: java, maven, osgi, declarative-services, pax-exam

I have created an [OSGi example project](https://github.com/mbe24/mode) and want to improve the provisioning of the bundles needed for the integration test.

Right now the bundles are statically references by file name, utilizing `CoreOptions.bundle("reference:file:" + <path>)`, the problem thereby is that the test will fail at some time in the future, when the name of the jars changes (due to version change for example).

Is there a better way to deploy the needed dependencies? Maybe with the use of a symbolic name, or group/artifact id?

```
@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
public class ServiceTestCase {

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    @Configuration
    public Option[] config() {
        return CoreOptions.options(
                /* needed for ds annotations */
                CoreOptions.mavenBundle("org.apache.felix", "org.apache.felix.scr", "1.8.2"),
                CoreOptions.bundle("reference:file:../service/target/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"),
                CoreOptions.bundle("reference:file:../service.impl/target/service.impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"),
                CoreOptions.junitBundles());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInjections() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(service);
    }
}
```

<sup>shortened version of [ServiceTestCase.java](https://github.com/mbe24/mode/blob/master/service.test/src/test/java/org/beyene/mode/service/test/ServiceTestCase.java)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is a maven project and bundles maven artifact. It's better then to use  `mavenBundle` references:

1. Reference these dependencies in the pom of your test
2. Use the `depends-maven-plugin` to generate a property file with the version of the dependencies:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.tooling</groupId>
       <artifactId>depends-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>generate-depends-file</id>
               <phase>generate-resources</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>generate-depends-file</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Use a `mavenBundle` reference :

   ```
   mavenBundle().groupId("org.beyene.mode")
     .artifactId("service.consumer").versionAsInProject()
   ```

Comment: Thx for your answer. What scope should I use for the dependencies in the test pom? Provided?

Comment: the test scope, but honestly, it doesn't matter. pax-exam will provide a new container, the classpath of the test will not be used.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is working fine from the command line. Eclipse is complaining, though: `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.servicemix.tooling:depends-maven-plugin:1.2:generate-depends-file (execution: generate-depends-file, phase: generate-resources)` Do you know sth. about that?

Comment: that's just eclipse which doesn't know anything about the `depends-maven-plugin` and doesn't know what to do. You can tell it to ignore this plugin.